# How can I make an arrowed navbar using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-tabs

I am able to design nav tabs using code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But i want my tabs design with arrows to right side as in picture. I will be glad if someone can help me out what is the css for this. Thanks.
[image: navbar]

Comment: use `before, after`

Comment: its not a how to forum.

Comment: If you are not strong with the force (of CSS), I would suggest you to look for breadcrumbs libraries, because it's not an easy task of copy/paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design pattern I think is really a "breadcrumb". the first thing that comes up in google is: [how to css breadcrumb](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_breadcrumbs.asp). I don't particularly like w3schools, but it's a good starting point, then you can just play w/ the styles from there.

As far as the arrows, you may want to check out [CSS Triangle generator](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/)